# How to add the primary key and I have increment the record 1 by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have to add a auto_Increment primary key column to the table. I used this script to create but its doing fine. but one thing is thtat I have alredy have a primary key in that table. so its throwing an error.

how to remove alredy existing primary and making a new auto_increamtn column has a primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE ABCD ADD ABCD_Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop the PRIMARY key constraint first, something like

```
ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Table_Col
```